# Query about setting up a guitar

Tags: guitar, setup, string-gauge, semi-acoustic-guitar, lefties

I have recently bought LTD AC 10E left handed. It came with a set of 10s and it is tuned half step down. Now I mostly tune standard B or C and use a higher gauge. So if I put a set of 12s on this guitar but tune it to standard C will I have to align the guitar?

Comment: Please explain what  'standard B or C' is. I've never heard of either.

Comment: @Tim I'm pretty sure he means B E A D F# B (low to high) or C F A# D# G C, the latter of which makes sense strung with 12s for having a similar total tension as standard tuning with 9s or 10s.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - thanks for the info. I wasn't aware that it had become 'standard' ! Interesting use of A# and D#, as opposed to their more usual names of Bb and Eb respectively - harking back to comments in a previous question, I think.

Comment: @Tim The word "standard" here means not dropped or open (or other). As in the standard string relationships. At some point this breaks down. For example, would "dropped C" mean C A D G B E or C G C F A D? Often spelling out all the strings is the best way.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - that makes sense now. Although 'Industry Standard' is a term I'm more familiar with; that would make sense as in - 'it's in tune with itself like a normal guitar, only lowered'.

Answer (score 2):

Every time you change the string gauge or tuning it's a good idea to check the setup/action. When I make a major change, I like to take it to a pro to get a setup, at least on my best guitars. My beater guitars and when I make minor changes, I do it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'll need to adjust, maybe not, but nothing in what you've described suggests any risk of damage to the instrument. My advice is to make the string gauge and tuning changes you want, wait a few hours, and tweak the action (via truss rod first and saddle height second) as needed. There are tons of online instructionals for how to do this.